# Is it possible to have SCIP and and python-zibopt work under windows?

Tags: scip

Recently I want to try some open source solvers instead of CPLEX. I found that PICOS + zibopt may be a good choice. However, I can merely find instruction on how to make zibopt work with python under windows properly. I downloaded the windows libraries (.dll file) of scip, and I try to install python-zibopt according to the command "python setup.py install". The error " blockmemshell/memory.h no such file" always popped out. I felt that it is because my compiler, which is VS120COMNTOOL, doecn't find the scip solver. Is there any chance that I can make scip work under windows now?

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look at the current python interface of SCIP 3.1.0? It uses the library from the SCIP Optimization Suite so you don't have to link another LP solver to SCIP.
On Windows, please try this modified setup.py file:

```
import sys, os, readline, glob, platform
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
from Cython.Build import cythonize

BASEDIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
BASEDIR = os.path.dirname(BASEDIR)
BASEDIR = os.path.dirname(BASEDIR)
INCLUDEDIR = os.path.join(BASEDIR,'src')
BASEDIR = os.path.dirname(BASEDIR)

#identify compiler version
prefix = "MSC v."
i = sys.version.find(prefix)
if i == -1:
  raise Exception('cannot determine compiler version')
i = i + len(prefix)
s, rest = sys.version[i:].split(" ", 1)
majorVersion = int(s[:-2]) - 6
minorVersion = int(s[2:3]) / 10.0

if platform.architecture()[0].find('64')>=0:
  LIBDIR  = os.path.join(BASEDIR,'vc'+str(majorVersion),'scip_spx','x64','Release')
else:
  LIBDIR  = os.path.join(BASEDIR,'vc'+str(majorVersion),'scip_spx','Release')
print('BASEDIR='+ BASEDIR)
print('INCLUDEDIR='+ INCLUDEDIR)
print('LIBDIR='+ LIBDIR)

def complete(text, state):
  return (glob.glob(text+'*')+[None])[state]

readline.set_completer_delims(' \t\n;')
readline.parse_and_bind("tab: complete")
readline.set_completer(complete)

libscipopt = 'lib/libscipopt.so'
includescip = 'include/scip'

ext_modules = []

ext_modules += [Extension('pyscipopt.scip', [os.path.join('pyscipopt', 'scip.pyx')],
                      #extra_compile_args=['-g', '-O0', '-UNDEBUG'],
                      include_dirs=[INCLUDEDIR],
                      library_dirs=[LIBDIR],
                      #runtime_library_dirs=[os.path.abspath('lib')],
                      libraries=['spx', 'scip_spx'])]
                      #libraries=['scipopt', 'readline', 'z', 'gmp', 'ncurses', 'm'])]

setup(
  name = 'pyscipopt',
  version = '0.1',
  description = 'wrapper for SCIP in Python',
  author = 'Zuse Institute Berlin',
  author_email = 'scip@zib.de',
  license = 'MIT',
  cmdclass = {'build_ext' : build_ext},
  ext_modules = ext_modules,
  packages=['pyscipopt']
)
```